# Opposite of Interface Segregation Principle

Tags: java, design-patterns, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

I was asked today in a interview what is the Interface Segregation Principle and what is the opposite case or principle to this one.

The ISP is clear for me but I don't know the second part of the question, what is the opposite principle to the ISP?

Comment: I suppose [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)

Comment: I can think of some terms:
- Overspecification: when interface specifies many capabilities that will be forced on client classes that do not necessarily need it
- Prémature Generalization : its when you create an interface before there was already a pattern emerging from different classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

The opposite of that would be a client that is *forced* to depend on methods that it doesn't use.  This might manifest itself in either implementing an interface that it doesn't require, the interface having methods at too broad of a layer, or a class that has several abstract methods defined that are not necessary to the client.

An example (first with interfaces):

```
public interface Book {

    String getAuthor();
    String getGenre();
    String getPageCount();
    String getWeight();
}

public interface EBook extends Book {
    // Oh no - ebooks don't have weight, so that should always return zero!
    // But it makes no sense to include it as an attribute of the interface.
}
```

An example with abstract methods:

```
public abstract class Shape {

    public abstract double getVolume();
    public abstract double getHeight();
    public abstract double getLength();
    public abstract double getWidth();
    public abstract Color getColor();
}

public class Line extends Shape {

    public double length;
    public Color color;

    // Kind of forced to have a volume...
    public double getVolume() {
        return 0;
    }

    /// ...and a height...
    public double getHeight() {
        return 0;
    }

    // ...and a width...
    public double getWidth() {
        return 0;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Makoto, Can a line be a shape?...a possible LSP violation as well.